# UnicodeWarning: special characters in Tkinter

Tags: python, encoding, tkinter, character

I have written a program in Tkinter (Python 2.7), a scrabblehelper in Norwegian which contains some special characters (`æøå`), which means my wordlist (ordliste) contains words with special characters.

When I run my function finnord(c*), it returns 'cd'. I am using an `entry.get()` to get the word to put in my function.

My problem is with the *encoding* of entry.get(). I have local coding `UTF-8`, but I get an `UniCodeError` when I am writing any special characters in my entrybox and matching them to my wordliste.

Here is my output.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\pythonprog\scrabble\feud.py", line 46
if s not in liste and s in ordliste:
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode -    
interpreting them as being unequal
```

When i write in my shell:

```
> ordinn.get()
u'k\xf8**e'
> ordinn.get().encode('utf-8')
'k\xc3\xb8**e'
> print ordinn.get()
kø**e
> print ordinn.get().encode('utf-8')
kÃ¸**e
```

Anyone knows why I can't match ordinn.get() (entry) to my wordlist ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce the error this way:

```
% python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'k\xf8**e' in [u'k\xf8**e']
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

So perhaps `s` is a `str object`, and `liste` or `ordliste` contains `unicode`, or (as eryksun points out in the comments) vice versa. The solution is to decode the `str object`s (most likely with the `utf-8` codec) to make them `unicode`.

If that does not help, please print out and post the output of

```
print(repr(s))
print(repr(liste))
print(repr(ordliste))
```

---

I believe the problem can be avoided by converting all strings to `unicode`.

1. When you generate `ordliste` from `norsk.txt`, use
   `codecs.open('norsk.txt','r','utf-8')`:

   ```
   encoding = sys.stdin.encoding
   with codecs.open('norsk.txt','r','utf-8') as fil:
       ordliste = [line.rstrip(u'\n') for line in fil]
   ```
2. Convert all user input to unicode as soon as possible:

   ```
   def get_unicode(widget):
       streng = widget.get()
       try:
           streng = streng.decode('utf-8')
       except UnicodeEncodeError:
           pass
       return streng
   ```

---

So perhaps try this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import codecs
import itertools
import sys

alfabetet = (u"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
             u"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER AE}"
             u"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE}"
             u"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE}")

encoding = sys.stdin.encoding
with codecs.open('norsk.txt','r',encoding) as fil:
    ordliste = set(line.rstrip(u'\n') for line in fil)

def get_unicode(widget):
    streng = widget.get()
    if isinstance(streng,str):
        streng = streng.decode('latin-1')
    return streng

def siord():
    alfa=lagtabell()
    try:
        streng = get_unicode(ordinn)
        ordene=finnord(streng,alfa)
        if len(ordene) == 0:
            # There are no words that match
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Dessverre..','Det er ingen ord som passer...')
        else:
            # Done: The words that fit the pattern
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Ferdig',
                'Ordene som passer er:\n'+ordene.encode('utf-8'))
    except Exception as err:
        # There has been a mistake .. Check your word
        print(repr(err))
        tkMessageBox.showerror('ERROR','Det har skjedd en feil.. Sjekk ordet ditt.')

def finnord(streng,alfa): 
    liste = set()
    for substitution in itertools.permutations(alfa,streng.count(u'*')):
        s = streng
        for ch in substitution:
            s = s.replace(u'*',ch,1)
        if s in ordliste:
            liste.add(s)
    liste = [streng]+list(liste)
    return u','.join(liste)+u'.'

def lagtabell():
    tinbox = get_unicode(bokstinn)
    if not tinbox.isalpha():
        alfa = alfabetet
    else:
        alfa = tinbox.lower()
    return alfa

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('FeudHjelper av Martin Skow Røed')
root.geometry('400x250+450+200')
# root.iconbitmap('data/ikon.ico')

skrift1 = tk.Label(root,
                text = '''\
Velkommen til FeudHjelper. Skriv inn de bokstavene du har, og erstatt ukjente med *.
F. eks: sl**ge
Det er kun lov til å bruke tre stjerner, altså tre ukjente bokstaver.''',
                font = ('Verdana',8), wraplength=350)
skrift1.pack(pady = 5)

ordinn = tk.StringVar(None)
tekstboks = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = ordinn)
tekstboks.pack(pady = 5)

# What letters do you have? Eg "ahneki". Leave blank here if you want all the words.
skrift2 = tk.Label(root, text = '''Hvilke bokstaver har du? F. eks "ahneki". La det være blankt her hvis du vil ha alle ordene.''',
                font = ('Verdana',8), wraplength=350)
skrift2.pack(pady = 10)

bokstinn = tk.StringVar(None)
tekstboks2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = bokstinn)
tekstboks2.pack()

knapp = tk.Button(text = 'Finn ord!', command = siord)
knapp.pack(pady = 10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Or the word lists are UTF-8 (`'k\xc3\xb8**e'`) and s from `Entry.get()` is Unicode that hasn't been encoded. It yields the same error.

Comment: repr(%), s, liste and ordliste all returns the same value as their original. [link](http://pastebin.com/0MfJVLqf) **bold** here is my script. I can'

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks for the comment. I think `try..except` is safer than using `isinstance` here. I'm not smart enough to account for all the ways decode might fail. :)

I'm confused by your comment "Decoding unicode ... might raise UnicodeDecodeError if the default encoding isn't 'ascii' and different from sys.stdin.encoding". We're dealing with Python2 here, and the default encoding is always 'ascii' under Python2. So how do you generate a UnicodeDecodeError?

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks for the help. Can the ASCII `str` returned by `StringVar.get` always be correctly decoded with `latin-1` regardless of the value of `sys.stdin.encoding`?

Comment: @eryksun: If a user types `€` (encoded in cp1252) into a Tkinter Entry, will Tkinter/TCL successfully convert it to unicode, or will it blindly try to decode it with utf-8? The code you linked to seems to say it will blindly try `utf-8`. Would it then fail, and return `PyString_FromStringAndSize(s, len)`? I haven't been able to track down the definition of this function. Is it still guaranteed to return an ASCII str? How can it when `€` contains the high bit?

Comment: I don't know the details of how Tk/TCL works with code pages / UTF across the supported operating system, but TCL strings are UTF-8 and its C API (e.g. `tcl_getvar2ex`) returns UTF-8 encoded bytes. (I know on Windows Tk uses UTF-16, so characters beyond the BMP become surrogate pairs.) Functions in _tkinter such as [FromObj](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Modules/_tkinter.c#l1020) decode non-ASCII strings as `unicode`. For example, '€' returns `u'\u20ac'`, 'Ā' returns `u'\u0100'`, '¡' returns `u'\xa1'`, but '~' returns ASCII '~' (`'\x7e'`).

Comment: To clarify the statement about Windows, I meant it uses UTF-16 in GUI controls such as the Entry. Pasting in a non-BMP character such as '' (`u'\U000f202a'`) shows up as 2 boxes in the control (`u'\udb88'` and `u'\udc2a'`). Blah...

Comment: There are some significant problems still (in many places and many pieces of software) with non-BMP characters, and even the availability of fonts that support non-BMP characters (a critical requirement for anything else to be fixed) is distinctly mixed.