# How to write labels in Arabic tkinter Combobox?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How to Write Labels in Arabic python tkinter Combobox

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

v = ["تصنيفات","نصنيفات"]
combo = Combobox(t, values=v, state="readonly")
combo.place(x=758, y=145)
print combo.get()
```

The result

```
╩╒غو▌
```

Comment: What is the `t` variable?

Comment: Relevant [unicodewarning-special-characters-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036499/unicodewarning-special-characters-in-tkinter)

Comment: What is the t variable? : t=Tk()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the problem running the following code with Python 2.7.15. It didn't require doing anything special to handle Arabic values.

Note that Tkinter is event-driven, which means that everything that happens much occur while its `mainloop()` is running. To `print` the current value of the `Combobox` required defining a callback function (`value_changed()` in the code below) and "binding" it to the virtual event that Tkinter generates whenever the value of the bound `Combobox` widget changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox


t = Tk()
t.geometry('1000x600')  # Make window big enough to display Combobox.

v = ["تصنيفات","نصنيفات"]
combo = Combobox(t, values=v, state="readonly")
combo.place(x=758, y=145)

def value_changed(event):
    """ Combobox callback function. """
    print 'combo.get():', combo.get()

combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', value_changed)  # Bind event-handling function.

t.mainloop()
```

And here's a screenshot showing the `Combobox` being displayed with Arabic values:

[image: screenshot showing the Combobox with Arabic values]

Answer (score 1):

Try this please in the top of the file:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Comment: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: